# A linear regression with recursive feature elimination resulted in zero and large coefficients - . Is that right?

Tags: python, time-series, linear-regression, cross-validation, feature-selection

I am trying to build a simple linear regression model with RFE using sklearn. I got  49 features selected. When I inspected the coefficients I found some of them very large and others are zeros. The data is energy demand timeseries, and some features supposed to influence the predictions are getting zero coefficients as shown in teh graphs. Appreciate your help.

Here is the RFECV code:

```
regr_cv = RFECV(estimator=regr,
         cv=tscv,
         scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
         verbose=2,
         n_jobs=-1)
```

and the result of the fit

```
Pipeline(memory=None, steps=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[2, 3, 4], dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=False)), ('rfecv', RFECV(cv=TimeSeriesSplit(max_train_size=None, n_splits=3),
estimator=LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False), n_jobs=-1, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', step=1, verbose=2))])
```

The cross validation results are

```
cv_results = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'cv_score': 
regr_pipe.named_steps['rfecv'].grid_scores_})
cv_results['mean_squared_error'] = cv_results['cv_score']
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(cv_results.index, cv_results['mean_squared_error'])
plt.xlabel('number of features')
plt.title('CV negative mean squared error')
plt.show()
```

[cross-validation results graph (sorry, Stackoveflow does not allow me to inline them here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP0JC.png)

And finally, the coefficients displayed against their corresponding features

```
coefs = supported_features.loc[supported_features['supported'], ].copy()
coefs['coefficients'] = regr_pipe.named_steps['rfecv'].estimator_.coef_
coefs.plot.bar('feature', 'coefficients', figsize=(15, 3), legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[features vs Coefficients graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C1Ik.png)

Many thanks

Comment: Just a question: why did you one-hot encode the hour of the day and the month of the year? These are numeric variables so it would seem to make more sense to leave them as numbers. This would also cut down on the number of features you have!

Comment: @caseWestern, because they are categorical features. More specifically, we need to binarize these categorical features. See [this article](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f) for more explanation

Comment: A categorical variable has no inherent ordering. Because hour of the day and month of the year actually do have an ordering (for example, 8 am is greater than 6 am) they are best described as ordinal variables (refer to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245866/is-hour-of-day-a-categorical-variable)). Hour of the day is generally never one-hot encoded, instead it it transformed into a cyclical representation as [discussed here](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/encoding-cyclical-features-24hour-time/).

Comment: No problem, this material can be a little tough to grasp. Your code looks on point, but maybe reading a little more about the concepts might be helpful!

Comment: I am a bit late to the game here, but for coefficients to be comparable in a linear regression, the variables need to be in similar scales. Of course I don't know your data and it might be that they already are. But in case they are not, in the pipeline, I would add one scaler, like the standard scaler or the MinMaxScaler from sklearn. Alternatively, set the parameter normalize=True within the Linear model.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from handling categorical data variables - thanks to @caseWestern - I got better results by adding to the training some features of autocorrelations of the energy data signal on a one-hour interval basis.

[training data table with autocorrelation features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dEEb.png)